# spark Cassandra tuning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

How to set following Cassandra write parameters in spark scala code for 
version - DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector **1.6.3**.

Spark version - 1.6.2

spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows

spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes

spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes

spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector 1.6.X, you can pass these parameters as part of your `SparkConf`.

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.123.10")
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")            
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")
    .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows", "100")            
    .set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes", "100")
    .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes", "100")            
    .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key", "partition")

val sc = new SparkContext("spark://192.168.123.10:7077", "test", conf)
```

You can refer to this [readme](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b1.6/doc/1_connecting.md) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way is to add those variables in a file, such as **spark.conf**:

```
spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes 10
```

etc...
and then create your spark context in your app with something like:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

and finally, when you submit your app, you can specify your properties file with:

```
spark-submit --properties-file spark.conf ...
```

Spark will automatically read your configuration from spark.conf when creating the spark context
That way, you can modify the properties on your spark.conf without needing to recompile your code each time.